# How to use Regular Expressions to find duplicate non-consecutive words?

Tags: python, regex

I need to reprint lines of a poem which coincide with specific rules. The rule I have been having trouble with is reprinting a line if the line has a word which appears more then once.

For example, `I have to go out with Jane` would not print. Whereas, `I have to go out to the movies with Jane` would print as the word `to` is repeated in the line.

```
Rules = ['']

Yip = open('poem.txt', 'r')
Lines = Yip.read().split('\n')

n = 1
for r in Rules:
i = 1
print("\nMatching rule", n)
for ln in Lines:
    if re.search(r, ln):
        print(i, end = ", ")
    i = i + 1
n = n + 1
```

I've gotten the code `'(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+'`, this finds duplicate words but only consecutively.

Likewise I've gotten to `'^(?=(.*?to){2}).*$'`, this is I believe my closest code. It will print the line above as it finds both instances of 'to' but the problem is it only hits the 'to'.

I'm trying to figure out if theres a way to write the code which will print the line if it finds a non-consecutive duplicate of any word in the line so it will work on any line given.

Comment: adding an example input and output can help users to show you how their solution work and focus exactly what you need

Comment: Is there a reason you _have_ to use regex?  A Counter that you fed `ln.split()` to would achieve the same without the overhead of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

The general regex that matches consecutive and non-consecutive duplicate words is

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQLpkA/1)

To make the pattern search for duplicate words across lines, make sure `.` matches line break chars, for example:

```
 (?s)\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)
 ^^^^
```

Or, use `re.S`  or `re.DOTALL` in Python `re`.

To make it case insensitive, add `i` modifier, or use `re.I` / `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
 (?si)\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)
 ^^^^^
```

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (letters, digits, `_`)
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=.*?\b\1\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\b\1\b` - Group 1 value as whole word (we need to use `\b` word boundaries again here since `\1` does not "remember" the context where `(\w+)` matched).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/iUHpWT):

```
import re
strs = ['I have to go out with Jane','I have to go out to the movies with Jane']
rx = re.compile(r'(?si)\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)')
for s in strs:
    print(s, "=>", rx.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
I have to go out with Jane => []
I have to go out to the movies with Jane => ['to']
```